# detect 4 permutations of 2 variable values in a switch case statement

Tags: math, coding-style, geometry

I have 2 variables, `width` and `height` as integers. Any of these can be positive or negative (not zero). So naturally there are 4 cases;

1. `width > 0 && height > 0`
2. `width > 0 && height < 0`
3. `width < 0 && height > 0`
4. `width < 0 && height < 0`

Now I want to take different action on each of these 4 cases without using 4 if statements.

Is there a way to aggregate these cases so that it can be put as a simple `switch case`

```
switch( aggregate ){
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
}
```

If there is no better way than using `if` for each then in 3D space you have 3 lengths `(x,y,z)` and there will be 27 `if` blocks.

I'm using **javascript** if that matters.

Comment: A 4-way `switch` and four mutually-exclusive `if` blocks are basically the same thing. If, in your 3d case, you do actually need to do one of 27 completely different things depending on the facts, then you're going to end up with 27 blocks of code, however they're organised...

Comment: ...to add, I'm guessing that the 4 (or 27) blocks aren't actually going to be doing *completely* different things - in fact, I'd wager that they could be made to all be doing the *same* thing, with two or three parameters taking the values `+1` and `-1`.

Comment: Why 27 if blocks? You have 2 choices per dimension, 2^3 = 8. Assuming you can't have 0s in this case too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **javascript** this is quite easy, just turn the condition upside down:

```
switch(true)
{
    case (width > 0 && height > 0):
        break;
    case (width > 0 && height < 0):
        break;
    case (width < 0 && height > 0):
        break;
    case (width < 0 && height < 0):
        break;

    default:

}
```

This also works in VB6/VBA but not in many other languaguages like C++ and C#.

Here's a simple proof: http://jsfiddle.net/avuxj/

Answer (score 3):

You could treat each of your conditions (width positive, height positive) as a single boolean attribute and combine them to binary number and switch over it.

Pseudocode:

```
int v = (width > 0 ? 0 : 1) << 1 | (height > 0 ? 0 : 1) << 0;
switch (v) {
  case 0b00:
    // width < 0 && height < 0;
    break;
  case 0b01:
    // width < 0 && height > 0;
    break;
  case 0b10:
    // width > 0 && height < 0
    break;
  case 0b11:
    // width > 0 && height > 0
    break;
}
```

If the language of your choice doesn't have binary numeric literals, then it's not as readable, but you might be able to fix that with comments.

Also note that languages that support interpreting `true` as `1` and `false` as `0` will help make the `int v = ...` line shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var bits=0;
if(width > 0) {
     bits+=1;
}
if(height > 0) {
     bits+=2;
}

switch{bits} {
    case 0: //both negative
        //something
        break;
    case 1: //width positive, height negative
        //something
        break;
    case 2: //width negative, height positive
        //something
        break;
    case 3: //both positive
        //something
        break;
}
```

Although it is all bit confusing. (Especially if You have 3 values). You can use variables to make Your code bit clearer.

```
var WIDTH_POSITIVE_BIT=1;
var HEIGHT_POSITIVE_BIT=2;

var bits=0;
if(width > 0) {
     bits+=WIDTH_POSITIVE_BIT;
}
if(height > 0) {
     bits+=HEIGHT_POSITIVE_BIT;
}

switch{bits} {
    case 0: //both negative
        //something
        break;
    case WIDTH_POSITIVE_BIT: //width positive, height negative
        //something
        break;
    case HEIGHT_POSITIVE_BIT: //width negative, height positive
        //something
        break;
    case WIDTH_POSITIVE_BIT+HEIGHT_POSITIVE_BIT: //both positive
        //something
        break;
}
```

I'd say that this does not help to make the code much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do this without adding a little overhead.

```
s = ( width < 0 ) ? 0 : 1;
s += ( height < 0 ) ? 0 : 2;

switch(s) {
    case  0: // 00 => both < 0
    case  1: // 01 => width > 0, height < 0
    case  2: // 10 => width < 0, height > 0
    case  3: // 11 => both > 0
}
```

And this could work for a 3D case:

```
s = ( width < 0 ) ? 0 : 1;   //First bit for width
s += ( height < 0 ) ? 0 : 2; //Second bit for height
s += ( depth < 0 ) ? 0 : 4;  //Third bit for depth

switch(s) {
    case  0: // 0 0 0
    case  1: // 0 0 1
    case  2: // 0 1 0
    case  3: // 0 1 1
    case  4: // 1 0 0
    case  5: // 1 0 1
    case  6: // 1 1 0
    case  7: // 1 1 1
}
```

Of course assuming you can't have a 0 dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Several answers are logically correct. If you were doing this in C it would be:

```
s = ((width<0)<<1) | (height<0);
switch(s) {
....
}
```

This can make a huge difference. I have code that combines 9 conditions into a switch like this. The switch gets turned into a jump table and is much faster than evaluating a bunch of conditions. There is no branching, just the jump table. I can't really speak to anything java or java script though.

You may also do nested if statements:

```
if (witdh<0) {
    if (height<0) {
        // both negative
    }
    else {
        // only width negative
    }
 }
 else {
    if (height<0) {
        // only height negative
    }
    else {
        // both positive
    }
 }
```

I find mashing the condition bits together and using a switch to be more readable - especially if the number of conditions grows.