# Better solution than nested if-else?

Tags: php, coding-style, if-statement

Not sure how this describe this with a better title, however here is my problem:

i have a replace function with multiple boolean options:

1. regex
2. whole words (only when regex==false)
3. case sensitive

and this means i have to choose 1 of 4 ways to replace my text. Currently my code looks like this:

*(those options here are indeed true/false as a string, passed in via POST from a set of [jquery checkboxes](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/))*

```
    if($regex=='true')
    {
        if($casesens=='true')
        {
            $p->aData['body'] = preg_replace('/'.$q.'/', $r, $p->aData['body']);
        }
        else
        {
            $p->aData['body'] = preg_replace('/'.$q.'/i', $r, $p->aData['body']);           
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($wwords=='true')
        {
            $q = " ".$q." ";
            $r = " ".$r." ";
        }
        if($casesens=='true')
        {
            $p->aData['body'] = str_replace($q, $r, $p->aData['body']);
        }
        else
        {
            $p->aData['body'] = str_ireplace($q, $r, $p->aData['body']);
        }
    }
```

as you can see, if have to compare `$casesens` in both conditons, and this becomes increasingly complex if i have to add more options to the UI. 
Is there a better or more elegant way to write this?

Comment: I asked a similar question and got good answers, you may want to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360600/detect-4-permutations-of-2-variable-values-in-a-switch-case-statement

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace` in the first case and `str_replace` in the second?

Comment: @Evan Cordell : because the user can switch between Regex and plain text mode for searches and replacements

Comment: What is wrong with calling functions in the top level "then" and "else" branch and have simple ifs inside those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do the check for `$casesens` once and define a variable like this:

```
if($casesens=='true') {
    $case = 'i';
}
```

And then use it in the regex pattern just like any other variable:

```
$p->aData['body'] = preg_replace('/'.$q.'/'.$case, $r, $p->aData['body']);
```

This would solve the first `if`. As for the second one I can think of 2 ways:

1. Create a function similar to `str_replace` and `stri_replace` that takes an extra boolean argument, to ignore case or not and, call the appropriate string replace function.
2. You could use `preg_replace` instead of the string replace functions just like you previously did and use the same way to solve the problem as I explained above.

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` if regex==false, because i have to handle my input differently - especially if the users tries to replace html code or uses special chars, brackets etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you're problem. But the idea is that you can use `preg_replace` to simulate the same behavior as `str_replace`. Just use `preg_quote` on `$q`. This is basically the same as the solution proposed by @Hamish.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can certainly simplify what you have by cutting down a lot of unnecessary duplication, something like:

```
if(!$regex) $q = preg_quote($q);
elseif($words) $q = "\s{$q}\s/";
$q = "/{$q}/";
if($casesens) $q .= 'i';
$p->aData['body'] = preg_replace($q, $r, $p->aData['body']);
```

I wouldn't call that elegant, but at least it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP Ternary Operators to reduce the complexity

http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators